# Explain JMeter report results

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Can you please explain why throughput is almost the same but number of samples is much lower in run with 400 threads/users? Error% is same as well. Application under test is java, cpu load in both cases/runs is 90%
[image: JMeter generated report]

Answer (score 0):

How do both tests **durations** correlate? Throughput is being calculated like:

```
Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)
```

So my expectation is that your "400 users" test duration is ~2.5x times higher than for "150" users test.

References:

- [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Understanding Your Reports: Part 2 - KPI Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-2-kpi-correlations)

Comment: Dmitri, thanks, you are right, duration was different